# How to set the selected value of a combobox to a string value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I've spent a while looking for an answer but I haven't found anything that has worked for me so far. I have a system that saves the contents of a combobox to a database. When I get the contents back from the database, I'm trying to set the selected item of the combobox to the item returned from the database. for example:
XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" x:Name="cmbMyCmb" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="cmbMyCmb_SelectionChanged">
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Please Select"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
      <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
cmbMyCmb.SelectedValue = itemFromDatabase;
```

If I display the `itemFromDatabase` it shows "Item 2" and it is a string.

What I have on the form is an input form and a datagrid. When an item is selected from the datagrid I want the items to be displayed in the input form so they can be edited and updated. I have all other items displaying I just need this combobox to set the selected value to the string from the database.

Comment: Are you trying to set it from outside of the class it is contained?  If its value is private then you will have to create a property method to set the value. If you are using Visual Studio look in the properties for your combo box control and see if is set to private.

Comment: @LarryLane I'm trying to set it from the code behind. I had this :((ComboBoxItem)cmbMyCmb.SelectedItem).Content = itemFromDatabase;
But this was only changing the text of the "please select" rather than selecting the one that the string was equal to.

Comment: SelectedItem.Content = X, which set the content to X, but not change the selected item. Can you set `SelectedIndex` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `SelectedIndex="0"` in your combo definition and try this:

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cmbMyCmb" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="cmbMyCmb_SelectionChanged" Margin="99,104,117.4,157.8">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Please Select"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Item 3"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //get item from database here
        string itemFromDatabase = "Item 2";

        cmbMyCmb.SelectedValue = itemFromDatabase;
    }
```

[image]

Note I'm doing it in the `Loaded` event as a sample on how to change. If you do it in `SelectionChanged` event, the result is that whatever the user selects, your code behind is going to put it back to whatever value you want, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the code behind is inside of a button which sets the datagrid value to the combobox value, the code isnt inside the SelectionChanged event. That being said, your solution worked, so thanks!